# Tangent plane and Normal vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find a normal vector and tangent plane to the surface

$x^2+4y^2=z^2$ at $(3,2,5)$

So, this is what I have done:

$f(x,y,z) = x^2+4y^2-z^2$

Partial Differentiation gives:

$\nabla f(x,y,z) = (2x,8y,-2z)$

Substituting in:

$\nabla f(x,y,z) = (6,16,-10)$

My normal vector is

$\vec r(t) = (3,2,5) + t(6,16,-10)$

I was wondering if I am correct thus far? Also, from this, how do I get the tangent plane?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Muchly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Known the normal vector $v$ at the a point $P=(x_P,y_P,z_P)$ of the surface this gives you the equation of the tangent plane in $P$ :

$$v \cdot (x-x_P,y-y_P,z-z_P)=0.$$

Comment: So the tangent plane is

$6x+16y-10z=0$ ?

Comment: That is correct. You can simplify with $3x+8y-5z=0$.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to write the equation of the line , $r(t)$, which passes through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and is normal to the surface. $\nabla f(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a vector normal to the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. So the only things you needs to do are

1) Compute the unit normal by ${\bf{n}} = {{\nabla f} \over {\left\| {\nabla f} \right\|}}$ or any other vector parallel to that which can be $ \nabla f$ itself.

2) Write the equation of the plane passing through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$

$$ {\nabla f(\bf{x_0})} \cdot ( {\bf{x}} - {\bf{x_0}} )= \bf{0} $$

3) In your problem, computation is as follows

$$ {\bf{x_0}} = {(3,2,5)}\\
{\nabla f(\bf{x_0})}=(6,16,-10)
$$

and hence

$$\eqalign{
  & 6\left( {x - 3} \right) + 16\left( {y - 2} \right) - 10\left( {z - 5} \right) = 0  \cr 
  & 6x + 16y - 10z + \left( { - 18 - 32 + 50} \right) = 0  \cr 
  & 6x + 16y - 10z = 0 \cr} $$

is the equation of the tangent plane.

Comment: I have made a comment above, Is what I found correct, or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Comment: If you expand out your answer you get the same, apologies for not seeing this reponse, why would it be incorrect, the x,y and z components are equivalent, no?

Comment: @Clovers: Yes I just thought that some constant number will appear but it seems that sum of $-18-32+50$ is $0$! :)